# GIF Compression - Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, compression, gif

I'm using flutter_video_compress, video_compress too.
My only success in compressing a GIF (that gets made from a video), ends up turning it into a jpeg and uploading that, instead of a GIF.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to compress a GIF for upload on Flutter?

I'm not sharing what I've done at this point since it's purely ground level and I'd love anyones ideas on getting this done.

Thank you so much for any help/input!

Comment: same problem. Please share the solution if found a way